# Any example for sqlparams for elasticsearch-jdbc-river

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

As the document says:  sqlparams bind parameters for the SQL statement (in order)
Could anyone give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer here: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Ann-JDBC-River-Plugin-for-ElasticSearch-td4019418.html, search for "Bind parameter" and "Time-based selecting"

```
  curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
            "type" : "jdbc",
            "jdbc" : {
                "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
                "user" : "",
                "password" : "",
                "sql" : "select products.name as \"product.name\", orders.customer as \"product.customer.name\", orders.quantity * products.price as \"product.customer.bill\" from products, orders 
where products.name = orders.product and orders.quantity * products.price > ?",
                "params": [ 5.0 ]
            }
        }'
```